# How to get data from database to google map info window

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

i have this code to show the info window in google maps

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: latlng,
    content: 'Hello, world'
  });
```

and i have a php code to retrieve the address from the database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL =("SELECT address FROM theaters WHERE theater_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']) . "'");
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo "<b>Theater Address:</b><br>";
echo $row['address'] . "<br /><br />";
 }
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Now i need to get the address from database to infowindow's content field..how to do this? can anyone help me....thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and assign `$row` database values:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("theaterdb", $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $strSQL = "SELECT address FROM theaters WHERE theater_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']) . "'";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    mysql_close();
?>

<script>
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: latlng,
    content: '<b>Theater Address:</b><br> <?php echo $row['address']; ?>'
  });
</script>
```

For a side note, you can try to move your code to PDO as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, check this nice [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Getting_Row_Count).